How to draw a number of circles inscribed in a square so that the sum of the radii of the circle is greatest?
I have a square with length of side is $a$. How to draw a number of circles inscribed in a square so that the sum of the radii of the circle is greatest? In the below picture is six circles inscribed in a square. We can consider number of circles are 5, 6, ... We consider number of the circles is fixed.

I am sorry, I don't know how to start.
PS. Another style I see www.packomania.com
I see this question at https://www.mapleprimes.com. With n = 14, n= 15 I compare between Mathematica and Maple.



There are differences between the two programs.

Do you restrict the number of circles ? Otherwise, you can fill-in many small circles in the cracks.

Umm.... why not the limit of an infinite number of very small circles?

@DavidG.Stork Yes. Number of circles can be 5, 6, ...


We only test n=5,n=6.
We need three varaibles {x[i],y[i],r[i]} to determint a circle.
Set RegionWithin[reg, Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r[i]]], {i, 1, n}] to ensure that the Disk contain in reg=Rectangle[].
{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}] >= r[i] + r[j] ensure that the Disks are disjoined.

Clear["Global`*"];
reg = Rectangle[];
n = 5;
sol = NMaximize[{Sum[r[i], {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[RegionWithin[reg, Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r[i]]], {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[EuclideanDistance[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}] >= 
     r[i] + r[j], {i, n}, {j, i - 1}], 
   Table[r[i] > 0, {i, 1, n}]}, 
  Table[{x[i], y[i], r[i]}, {i, 1, n}] // Flatten, 
  Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]


Graphics[{EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[], 
  Rectangle[], {FaceForm[Red], 
    Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r[i]], {i, n}]} /. sol[[2]]}]



The cases n=6.



Very nice, but results are suboptimal if n=19, 20, 21, 22, and I assume also for many other larger values. For some reason, such results contain a cluster of smallish circles at or near the lower left corner, together with a vacant area elsewhere that will easily accommodate a larger circle than one of the small ones which could be removed.

There is a tendency for ∑r to increase with n. This often fails; n=17 gives a lower value than n=16; clearly n=16's ∑r could be increased by adding a small circle in any interstice, thus giving a higher value than the algorithm gives for n=17. I suspect either NMaximize has a bug, or it is being misused.

@JamesStein, it's not a bug. If you look at the documentation for NMaximize, there are methods which are guaranteed to give a global maximum (Convex, MOSEK, Gurobi ...). However, SimulatedAnnealing is a heuristic method, so there is no guarantee you will actually reach the global maximum.

@cvgmt Can I ask if it is possible to expand the answer to 3D?(I replaced with Ball and Cuboid but did not succeed)

@metroidman  You can ask a new question. I don't test the case of 3D before.
